# OP has deleted code from their question, so now it's unclear. Should I revert the edit and reinstate the code?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

Re this question: [Why can't I pass a int to a float in the same statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232264/why-cant-i-pass-a-int-to-a-float-in-the-same-statement?noredirect=1#comment71624629_42232264)

The original question was quite unclear and led to some speculative comments and one answer which (correctly) addressed the question of typecasting primitives and how that works.

The OP then added sample code to the question to illustrate their situation.  This revealed the issue wasn't casts or type conversion at all, but a compiler error because a method was being called with an incorrect parameter count.  However, before anyone posted an answer, the question was again edited, removing the code and leaving the original, unclear question.

Should I edit the question to reinstate the code, so a correct answer can be possible?  I originally thought I should, but the OP may very well have had good reason to remove the code from the question (e.g., copyright issues).  As-is, I think the question should probably be deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let the OP decide what they want their question to look like ultimately. They may have had good reasons to remove the code sample; either because they weren't allowed to post it in the first place (e.g. employer restrictions), or because they figured out it wasn't representative of their issue.

As is the question is completely unclear without a code sample, so treat it that way. If OP decides to add useful code again later, it can go through the reopen process.

Comment: Do we actually consider _either because they werent allowed to post in the first place_ a valid reasoning to remove something?

Comment: OP can request redaction of details which were never supposed to go public, so, yes, such things *can* be removed. In this case the code is still in the edit history, so that would defeat the purpose, but it's possible OP simply isn't aware of that. It's just an example reason that doesn't need to be deconstructed too deeply here.

Comment: I agee that a post should be able to be redacted, but I think this should happen in conjuncture with the moderation team. If the OP simply edits the post and removes code from his question without any visible reason, I think it should be rolled back, certainly if an answer has been given in a a specific context.