# OP deletes example code from my answer, can I prevent this?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago, I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42782122/962603) a question. At that point in time, the question had a link to a nice runnable example. Since then, OP has deleted that example and the link to it from their question. This [is fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344195/962603), but makes the question weaker. Oh well.

However, OP also went ahead and [edited my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42782122/revisions) to remove the example code from it. No explanation was given whatsoever. I did a rollback that was subsequently undone by OP. I commented asking why OP keeps doing this, but got no response so far.

When the consensus is that [we do not want to compromise the quality of our answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251924/962603), I am wondering what I can do about this? I can play the edit and rollback game for a long time, but I don't want to have to worry about this.

Are there other ways to contact OP? Is there anything I can do to prevent my answer from being made much less valuable than it could be, IMHO?

Comment: Flag your answer for moderator attention and explain exactly what is happening,

Comment: Apparently the OP deleted the codepen page. You don't happen to have the OP's code in your cache anywhere, by any chance?

Comment: @Cerbrus I know. I wish I did, but I don't... From now on I'm definitely going to save code that is only linked and not included in the question.

Comment: Just as an FYI, the question sounds like a student working on a class project. It's a common problem where a person [posts classwork](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295420/how-to-cope-with-complaints-from-tutors-who-want-to-fight-cheaters) and then tries to [scrub the site](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=33025415#33025415) so they don't get caught. A major problem caught by the edit monitor bots is people who edit their posts into garbage in a last-ditch effort to get rid of it

Comment: And that's why boys and girls, we prefer the code in the post themselves. Right now, no one knows what the code did.

Comment: I assume it's not just students but also employees who want to hide the fact that they posted code that belongs to their employer.

Comment: @Machavity I love how the post is much more likely to be seen now because he tried to scrub it.

Comment: It's a little disappointing that even ["trusted" users with enough rep to not have to go through the suggested edit queue for their edits](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) don't realize that this is sort of thing is "not okay".

Comment: Original question just got deleted.

Comment: well then, someone doesn't want his homework to be public.

Comment: The question is still in the google cache (no code though): http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:y8O3jtZox9YJ:stackoverflow.com/a/42782122/962603+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The first step when someone edits your answer in such away that it removes valuable info from the answer, or changes the answer, is to rollback, as you've done.

In the event that someone *keeps* trying to edit code out of your answer, despite your rollbacks, flag the post for moderator attention and explain what has happened, like Robert Longson mentioned above.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you happen to know what the moderators (can) do? Is it now actually impossible to edit the question? I cannot see this on the answer, but that may be because I wrote it originally.

Comment: The moderators can do anything from a friendly message (probably the most likely outcome in this case) to a temporary supension or a ban (probably not for this case), and lots of things in between (e.g. a "less friendly" message). They can (and *will*) also look at patterns of similar behavior, which (if they find them) might move the scales towards the "less friendly" part of the spectrum. I don't think it is possible to lock individual posts (such as your answer), only an entire question + all answers, but I might be wrong on that.

Comment: @Justastudent A not-uncommon response to an "edit war" is locking the post, preventing, IIRC, further edits, votes, comments and (in the case of questions) answers. Although I believe this is typically a short-term solution until things calm down. And if the post can't be made useful (like in the question's case, where code from the post is irretrievably gone from the mod's point of view), they may simply close it and possibly delete it. To deal with the actual behaviour, what Jörg said.

Comment: @JörgWMittag [Yes, you can lock individual answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201280/apache-not-starting-on-mamp-pro/25212463#25212463). I believe locking a question also necessarily prevents posting more answers (along with locking the question post itself), but the answers can still receive votes, edits and comments ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)).